# EF throws AspNetUsers error after Owin Authorization timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, owin

I have overridden the authorization in my `AccountController` for an `MVC5` app. It works fine logging in and logging out, getting the context, etc. However, if the authorization times out, instead of redirecting me back to the `Login` page, it throws the error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.

I'm not using `EF` in authentication, but rather a service, so I do not have these tables. However, I can't find where it is hitting this code to throw the error.

**AccountController.cs:**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var userRequest = new RequestObject
        {
            Name = model.Username,
            Password = model.Password
        };

        try
        {                
            var result = await client.LoginUserAsync(userRequest);

            if (result == 0)
            {
                var user = new User
                {
                    Name = model.Username
                };

                OwinSignIn(user);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // TODO: log error
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }


    private void OwinSignIn(User user, bool isPersistence = false)
    {
        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name)
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        var result = client.GetUserRoles(userRequest);
        var roles = result.Roles.ToList();

        if (roles.Any())
        {
            var roleClaims = roles.Select(r => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r.Name));
            identity.AddClaims(roleClaims);
        }

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistence }, identity);
    }
```

Again, this *only* happens if I am signed in and wait for that authorization to expire. I'm not sure what method I have not updated in order to make sure it just goes back to the `Login` page - I suspect there is something that is checking the session is still valid somewhere but I'm not sure where.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

If I remove the `OnValidateIdentity` call, the problem goes away. I'm not sure if this can be fixed or if removing it is ok...

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

Comment: You don't have a table called `AspNetUsers`? Weird. Have you searched for that string in your solution?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari - No, I do not have that table. As stated we have an existing web service that handles authentication against our own tables. Overriding the method in the question allows me to login using that. Something is happening on SessionEnd somewhere that is then going back and looking for that table. That string is not found anywhere in the solution, no.

Comment: Have you overriden the Authorize attribute?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari No. However, I just found the problem goes away if I remove the `RegenerateIdentity` call from `Startup.Auth.cs` - see update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you've already found a solution to your problem. If you are not using EF to persist your users data, then it will be safe to remove most of Identity packages from your solution and only leave required OWIN ones.

Reason you see this effect is because this bit:

```
OnValidateIdentity =     
    SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
```

It is executed on a request every 30 minutes and checks if the current cookie is the same as data in the database. Is actually calling default `ApplicationUserManager` that is by default wired into the EF and by default expect `AspNetUsers` table to be present. No, you won't find this string in your solution - this table is defined on `IdentityDbContext` and is provided by EF part of Identity.

I suspect it will be safe to make your `ApplicationDbContext` to inherit from `DbContext` rather than from `IdentityDbContext` - this will remove any possibility to hit missing tables that you don't need. Following that you can remove `ApplicationUserManager` (as it expects `IdentityDbContext`).

I've [blogged](http://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/)  about using AD as a service for setting OWIN cookie - some of this might be useful for you.

Comment: Yes, I was able to fix this by removing that bit. I'm marking this as answer since you've given a complete understanding as to what is happening. Your blog post is very helpful for anyone looking to replace the built in implementation. Thanks.